# Carrying over dependencies in Maven

Tags: maven-2

I am working on 3 maven projects.  They're all separate projects, but they share a common base framework.  Let's call the framework A and its dependencies B and C.

There is a library L that A depends on.  Any package that uses A will also need to use L, and it will need to use the same version of L that A does.  For this reason, I would like a way to specify L in A's pom and only in A's pom.  I don't want to have to go and edit B and C's poms every time I upgrade L.

Is there a way to do this?  There's not a parent pom that A, B, and C share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If B and C also uses library L directly then you should define that in B and C pom file. Since its a direct dependency it should be clear by looking into POM file.

Second option is if library L is common to A, B and C projects then you should define a parent pom.